# Referencing terraform_remote_state from within module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Using Terraform v0.13.5

I have a module which has some outputs derived from some sub modules within it, e.g.:

```
module "egressvnet" {
  source = "../modules/vnet/egress"
}

output "subnet" {
  value = module.egressvnet.subnet
}
```

`terraform output` confirms that what I expect to be outputted is.

Within another terraform setup I would like to reference the outputs from the above.

So I have this in my terraform config:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "network" {
  backend = "azurerm"

  config = {
    resource_group_name  = "xxx"
    storage_account_name = "xxx"
    container_name       = "terraform"
    key                  = "network.tfstate"
  }
}

module "web" {
  source = "../modules/web"

  subnet_id = terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.subnet

}
Is what I'm trying to do possible?
```

But when I do a plan I get this error:

```
Error: Reference to undeclared resource

  on base.tf line 111, in module "web":
 111:   subnet_id = terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.subnet

A managed resource "terraform_remote_state" "network" has not been declared in
the root module.
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/65877008/2291321 answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `terraform_remote_state` is a [data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/data-sources/index.html), you should refer to it using `data.`:

```
subnet_id = data.terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.subnet
```

Comment: thanks! Sometimes you can spend so long reading the docs you miss it staring you in the face!